# three ways to let PHP and a regular user edit the same files

Tags: server, file-permissions, rsync

I am a web developer, and for some upcoming projects I would like to use a file-based CMS. This means that many of the files I create at the start must be editable by the PHP user later, but also remain editable for my user (and also the other way around). My PC runs Debian 9, which I love but am not super knowledgeable about, and I have also just set up a local network server with Debian 9 for backups and possibly file sharing. (I'm using [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com) to configure this, which reflects my level of command line skills).

On my online shared hosting server, the PHP user and the FTP user seem to be the same, and 644/755 permissions work fine, this is also recommended by the CMS I'm using. I would like to mimic this on my computer so I don't have to fiddle with permissions all the time. But how do I do this? Currently, my regular user (`anna`) does not have access to `www-data`'s files and vice versa. Putting them in the same group still means changing file permissions. Making `anna` the PHP user is a Bad Idea (as far as I understand it) because `anna` has `sudo` permissions.

So far I have researched three possible solutions that I don't really know very much about, and I would like to know which is the best route to take.

1. Develop locally on my computer and use `apache-mpm-itk` or suPHP to let PHP edit the files (I got that idea from [this question on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/807723/www-data-security-issue-across-multiple-sites-in-a-vps/807728#807728)).
2. Develop locally on my computer and `rsync` the files to my server with `grunt-rsync`, and somehow get `rsync` to set the ownership to `www-data` ([another ServerFault thread helping here](https://serverfault.com/questions/564385/rsync-command-issues-owner-and-group-permissions-doesn%C2%B4t-change)).
3. Mount the project's *server* directory, which is owned by `www-data`, on my computer with [SSHFS](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8904) and then either edit the files on the server directly or copy them over from my local directory with `grunt-copy`.

What do you think: from a security and ease of use perspective, which is the best way? Or do you know an even better one?

Thank you for taking the time to read and think about this!
Anna~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! I finally ended up reading about running PHP as CGI instead of as an Apache module, and that this would solve my permissions problem. Plus, as far as I understand it, there are no extra security precautions to take when I'm the only one working with it on my local computer.

In case someone comes across this who might find it helpful, here's what I did (basically following [these instructions](https://www.devops.zone/webserver/installing-php7-fpm-with-apache2-worker-on-ubuntu/)):

1. I installed `php7.0-fpm`
2. Edited **/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf** and put the following just before `</VirtualHost>`:

   ```
   DirectoryIndex index.php
   <LocationMatch "^(.*\.php)$">
       ProxyPass fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/html
   </LocationMatch>
   ```
3. I activated the Apache module `proxy_fcgi` (via Webmin, which apparently does an automatic Apache restart)
4. In **/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf** I commented out a listen line and put another below like this:

   ```
   ; listen = /run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock
   listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
   ```
5. I then restarted PHP-FPM with this command: **/etc/init.d/php7.0-fpm restart** (a little different from the instructions, I'm on Debian 9). After that, phpinfo() gave me the Server API "FPM/FastCGI".
6. And finally, I changed the user and group from `www-data` to `anna` in three places, twice in **/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf** and then once more in **/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/php7.0-fpm.conf** (this last bit may be Ubuntu/Debian specific, my thanks go to Keith for a [comment on StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30190/how-do-i-set-the-user-of-php-fpm-to-be-php-user-instead-of-www-data#comment-828514)).

And that was it! :-)