# PHP-FPM solution that used to work now returns 404 for all subpages, index page still works

Tags: php, http-status-code-404

Quite some time ago, I needed to have the PHP user be the same as my home directory user, and I finally got that set up with PHP-FPM: [here's the old thread on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51342761/three-ways-to-let-php-and-a-regular-user-edit-the-same-files). Now I have a new computer and set it up with Kubuntu 19.10 instead of Debian 9. So far, this has proven a good choice for me, there's just one thing which I can't seem to figure out:

I have the same setup with php 7.3 via FPM and my own user as PHP user, all my projects under my home directory, and symlinks into `/var/www/html`. All the index pages turn up as expected under `localhost/symlink`, but all the files and directories below that return a 404 error no matter what I do, so neither `localhost/symlink/page` nor `localhost/symlink/page.html` will return anything but "File not found".

Admittedly my understanding of Apache directives is still patchy at best, and I don't really know what half of my configs are doing. I have also searched the internet fairly extensively, and while many people seem to have similar problems, they usually come with error messages in some log or other, but my Apache **and** PHP-FPM log are clean and show nothing out of the ordinary (I did put `LogLevel debug` in my sites-enabled config). In short: I am stumped. If anyone has any pointers, I really would love to read them!

Thank you for your time
**Anna~**

Answer (score 0):

… I found it. `mod_rewrite` wasn't enabled.